# SSRS report showing data when deployed but blank in preview

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report in SSRS. The source of the report is a SQL script that includes temp tables. There is a date variable and 29 fields are returned. 
I expect 3 results to be returned. When I preview the report 3 lines are returned but they are blank. When I deploy the report the 3 lines of data are visible and correct.
Can someone please advise on this rather strange issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any change they are looking at different databases? Do you have only one database?

Comment: seems like an issue with datasource connectivity

Comment: Just checked and the datasources are the same. There is no difference between the preview version and the deployed version. Other similar reports work fine.

Comment: Which datasources did you compare? I believe preview uses the one in your bin folder and of cuorse the published one uses the published datasource. In this situation I suggest you break out SQL Profiler and observe the SQL being submitted. It often results in a 'aaaaaaaah' moment. Do you have any row group filters in your report?

Comment: I have put the report live without being able to properly view in test. The datasources are not a factor. There are only 2 sets, 1 is live and 1 is an overnight copy. I will have to try the SQL Profiler. It is just very odd.